# Azure Service Principal cannot execute AZ REST MS Graph API commands

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Our Service Principal needs to execute some AZ REST API commands against MS GRAPH. For example the Service Principal should be able to execute the below command

```
az rest --method GET  --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/OBJECT_ID_OF_APP_REGISTRATION"
```

But when I execute the REST commands, it says "Insufficient privileges" I am logged in as the Service Principal (az login --service-principal -t abc -u abc -p abc ...)

```
az rest --method GET  --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/OBJECT_ID_OF_APP_REGISTRATION"
Forbidden({"error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.","innerError":{"date":"2022-10-12T08:10:43","request-id":"....","client-request-id":"....."}}})
```

Newly Added Permissions

[image]

PATCH Command

```
az rest --method PATCH --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{OBJECT_ID_OF_APP_REGISTRATION}" --headers 'Content-Type=application/json' --body  "{web:{redirectUris:['https://SOME_URL_HERE']}}"
Forbidden({"error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.","innerError":{"date":"2022-10-12T11:32:51","request-id":"...","client-request-id":"..."}}})
```

Comment: Please note that, you need to Grant Admin Consent for the added API permissions. As I can see Grant Admin Consent is greyed out for you so you have to contact admin to grant consent, and this will resolve your error.

Comment: @Rukmini What does 'Grant Admin Consent' means? Can you explain it? And what is the exact permission required to execute the 'az rest' commands? 'User.Read.All' will be enough?

Comment: To get an application, you need this **`Application.Read.All`** permission consented.

Comment: So if I give 'Admin Consent' to this application, ALL USERS in the Tenant will have access to this Application? Is that what it mean by Admin Consent?

Comment: Yes, if admin grants admin consent, then All users will be able to access Application. Application.Read.All needs Admin Consent.

Answer (score 0):

Please **note** that, to get the application details, you need **`Application.Read.All`** Application permission consented.

*I tried to reproduce in my environment and got the **application details successfully** like below:*

If the admin grants consent, then all the users will be able to access the Application.

**To resolve the error, administrator needs to grant admin consent to the API permission.**

[image]

I am able to get the application details successfully like below:

```bash
az rest --method GET --uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/ObjectID'
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Get application - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: I have added the correct permissions (Screenshot added above) But now I can execute 'az rest --method GET' command but I cannot execute 'az rest --method PATCH'

Comment: What is the error you are getting while running az rest --method PATCH? And could you please include the query you are using?

Comment: PATCH command added above

Comment: To do PATCH operation, you need Application.ReadWrite.All Application permission consented.

Comment: But Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy also should obviously have access?

Comment: Try using Application.ReadWrite.All Application permission and execute the query. Please check [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/W4y9fVi.png) for more in detail.

Comment: So basically, the Service Principal is trying to add the web-redirect-uris in another App Registration. Is that the problem why it says permission denied?

Comment: The App Registration which the SP is trying to add the redirect-uris wasn't created by this SP.

Comment: Yeah, that might be the issue.